# jquery: find common elements in 2 sets of divs

Tags: jquery

For a markup like this:

```
<div id="set1">
 <div id="100">a div</div>
 <div id="101">another div</div>
 <div id="102">another div 2</div>
 <div id="120">same div</div>
</div>  

<div id="set2">
 <div id="105">a different div>
 <div id="101">another div</div>
 <div id="110">more divs</div>
 <div id="120">same div</div>
</div>
```

As you can see both #set1 and #set2 contain 2 divs with the same id (101, 120). Is it possible somehow with jQuery to find the common elements and add a class to the divs in #set1 that have the same id with divs in #set2?

In other words after the script run the above code would look like this:

```
<div id="set1">
 <div id="100">a div</div>
 <div id="101" class="added">another div</div>
 <div id="102">another div 2</div>
 <div id="120" class="added">same div</div>
</div>  

<div id="set2">
 <div id="105">a different div>
 <div id="101">another div</div>
 <div id="110">more divs</div>
 <div id="120">same div</div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**
playing around with it i did something but i am not sure it can go anywhere. I created an array with the ids in both sets and in Firebug i can see an array with the values

```
 var arrEl = [];
   $('#set1 div, #set2 div').each( function(index) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');            
    arrEl.push(id);

 //maybe somehow check the array for the values that appear twice, and add the class to the //matching divs?
   });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is that really your markup? It would be invalid HTML to have elements with the same ids.

Anyway, I suppose you could loop through all divs in set1 and check if they exist in set2:

```
var $set2 = $('#set2');
var $duplicates = $.grep($('#set1 > div'), function(el) {
  return $set2.children('#' + el.id).length > 0;
});
$($duplicates).addClass('added');
```

See this in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/DDtQU/

Comment: no this is not my markup. It was a simplified example :) thanx

Answer (score 2):

IDs should never be duplicated within the same document, it breaks the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2) and jQuery will only ever select the first occurence in the document whenever the ID selector (e.g. '#foo') is called. Furthermore, results will be inconsistent across different browsers. I would suggest using a custom attribute (or [`$.data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/)) to store those reference numbers.

A custom attribute looks like this:

```
<div id="foo" custom="test">Hello</div>
```

You can get the value of `custom` like this:

```
alert($("#foo").attr("custom"));
```

Comment: jQuery will only return the first occurrence when nothing but id selector is used. If you do `$("#set2 #101")` or `$("#set2").find("#101")`, however, it will work as intuitively expected. And could you please elaborate on what are the implications of "breaking the spec" and what are some of the inconsistencies across browsers?

Comment: i would use data(). +never use numbers as ID's its not valid

Comment: @Fyodor - 'Breaking the spec' = "This name must be unique in a document." (from the W3C specification). As for inconsistencies across browsers - I do not have an example of that offhand, watch this space. Duplicate IDs per document is a terrible practice. Also, IE tends to choke on numeric IDs (which also break the spec).

Comment: ok guys relax, i m just playing with it, i ll use rel actually, i am aware of the IDs thing lol

Answer (score 1):

Given your comment that you're going to use `rel` instead of `id`, this way creates arrays (using `map()`) of each set, storing the value of `rel`, and compares them.

```
var set1 = $('#set1').children().map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('rel');
}).get();

var set2 = $('#set2').children().map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('rel');
}).get();

for(var i in set1) {
    if(set1[i] == set2[i])
        $('#set1').children().eq(i).addClass('added')
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

Or perhaps better (shorter anyway), try this:

```
$('#set2 > div').each(function(){
    $('[rel=' + $(this).attr('rel') + ']', '#set1').addClass('added')
});
```

Comment: nice one! but you could use $('#set2 > div') as selector.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, caught that just after I posted. Even more better-er now.

Answer (score 0):

Go through set1 in a loop and for each div, see if there is a matching one in set2:

```
var set2 = $("#set2");
var set1Divs = $("div", $("#set1));

for( var i = 0; i < set1Divs.size(); i++ )
{
    var div = set1Divs[i];
    var divId = div.attr( "id" );
    if ( set2.find( "#" + divId ).size() > 0 ) {
        div.addClass( "added" );
    }
}
```

Comment: i get an error on this line var divId = div.attr( "id" ); (div.attr is not a function)

Comment: or you can use: set1Divs.each(functon(o, i){  })

Answer (score 0):

even if your code is not gonna be valid, and that it is a very bad practice to have duplicate ID's and using numbers as ID's you can use this code. But don't tell anyone i wrote it :P

```
var campareTo = $("div#set1 > div") 
var original = $("div#set2 > div")

original.each(function(o, i){
   var tempID = $(this).attr("id")
   if (compareTo.filter("#" + tempID).length){
     compareTo.filter("#" + tempID).addClass('added')
   }
})
```

test it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/DDtQU/1/